# Xampp - Requiring Password When Accessed From Internet?

Tags: xampp

I have a xampp web server on the internet. I would like to know how to restrict access by password when the server is accessed from an external IP?

This should not apply to users on the local network. Local users don't
need to enter a password. Only external users do.

If a user tries to access the website via the internet, it should say:
"You Are Accessing A Private Web Server, Please enter the server Username/Pass To Continue. Once authenticated, you will have access to any directory. "

Answer (score 0):

create a **.htaccess** file  in the folder you want to protect from external visitors inside which write these:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/secretfile
AuthName "Protected Area"
require valid-user
Allow from 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0
Satisfy Any
```

replace 192.168.0.0 by your local network address and make the secret file by  [htpasswd](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/htpasswd/)